# I am not able to understand the logic behind this code ,It is a code of finding a GCD

Tags: python

I am not able to understand the logic behind this code ,It is a code of finding a GCD

```
def hcf(a, b):
    if(b == 0):
        return a
    else:
        **return hcf(b, a % b)**
  
# a = 60
# b = 48
  
# prints 12
# print("The gcd of 60 and 48 is : ", end="")
print(hcf(24, 40))
```

Comment: What do you not understand? The modulus operator? Recursion? How to use a [debugger](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html) to step through code line by line to see what's happening?

Comment: This is the recursive implementation of the [Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, function "hcf" is a function that can be called recursively.  The twist to this usage for deriving the greatest common denominator lies in the fact that on each subsequent call to the function, the previous denominator used for the modulo calculation becomes the numerator and the remainder from the previous modulo calculation becomes the denominator.

```
def hcf(a, b):
    if(b == 0):
        return a
    else:
        print("Try", b, "and", a % b)   # Every recursive call switches the numerator and denominator to be used for modula calculation
        return hcf(b, a % b)
  
# a = 60
# b = 48
  
# prints 12
# print("The gcd of 60 and 48 is : ", end="")
print(hcf(24, 40))
```

This process zeros in on the largest value that finally attains a remainder of zero, and thus is identified as the greatest common denominator.

Inserting a print statement to view what is happening at each recursive call of this function results in the following terminal output for the values coded into your program.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/GCD$ python3 gcd.py 
Try 40 and 24
Try 24 and 16
Try 16 and 8
Try 8 and 0
8
```

In an extreme example, if both numbers happen to be prime numbers, the greatest common denominator will be "1".

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/GCD$ python3 gcd.py 
Try 29 and 17
Try 17 and 12
Try 12 and 5
Try 5 and 2
Try 2 and 1
Try 1 and 0
1
```

It is an efficient method to attain the greatest common denominator for two natural numbers.

You might want to try out some different number combinations and review the printout to visually walk through the process.